Searching for an older body-swap movie
I'm looking for 80's or early 90's post-apocalyptic movie. I watched it at least 15 years ago I think. But the year of the movie was between 2013-2018. 
There was a young married couple. They were attacked by some guys. The guys weren't robbers or murderers. They attacked them for scientific purposes, to investigate their bodies. After the attack, the husband awoke to find himself in some kind of prison. But there were lots of women, instead of men. The place was very creepy. He suddenly realized that a wealthy man had transplanted his brain to his body, to keep up his life. His body had died, so he had his brain transplanted in a younger man. 
It was a project by some company full of scientists. For a charge, they were giving new bodies to wealthy people. The husband tried to escape from there with his own soul, body and brain and cooperated with some rebels and other guys in the same situation like him. Unfortunately I couldn't remember the rest of it. 
Some other details: 
Origin country: USA
Language: English 
Release year: 1980-1985
Duration: 80-120 mins

What do you mean by post-apocalyptic exactly? Radioactive wasteland?

Apart from the attack at the start - Freejack?

Memory Run (1995) aka Synapse

Set in a future society controlled by the nearly omnipotent Life Corporation, this action drama chronicles the fate of a renegade gun smuggler who sells weapons to a small rebel faction fighting against the huge conglomerate. The gun runner's ordeal begins after he is captured by government officials and killed. As part of a diabolical experiment, they take his still-living brain and place it in his recently-murdered girlfriend's body. Fortunately for the rebels, this action has dire consequences for the Corporation.




